# Is there an API to retrieve ERC-721 listings/bids from different marketplaces?

Tags: ethereum, nft, etherscan, opensea, erc721

I am trying to get listings and/or the latest bids for the same ERC721 token from different marketplaces (such as Opensea or Looksrare). I know that those platforms have their own APIs but none are commercially available.

Any of the following solutions will be enough to fix the problem

- retrieving the listing details since I know the collection address and the contract addresses of those marketplaces (either using Etherscan or any other commercially available API)
- retrieving the latest/highest bid for that token associated with marketplaces (either using Etherscan or any other commercially available API)

Comment: After trying couple of APIs, I found that [Reservoir](https://reservoir.tools) works best for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excellent question. The market is completely fragmented and for one to retrieve all the available pricing/listings/orders it needs a lot of legwork and connection to various APIs.

There are a few teams working on a common pricing API that can aggregate the pricing of an asset across exchanges and on multiple chains but none of them is public yet. One of that I know and I'm a beta user of is:

https://openstory.io

I also believe that Zora.co has a similar endpoint but only for the marketplaces that are built using their own API.

Answer (score 0):

you should give [module](https://www.modulenft.xyz/) a shot! They have all data from most NFT marketplaces, I hope that's what you're looking for

Comment: I also tried the module but they were missing data for some of the tokens. Instead I started using Reservoir (which covers Opensea, Looksrare and X2Y2)